# Android Map: How to detect ImageView overlapping on Map Marker?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

In my Map Activity i'm displaying few Markers indicating parking lots and i have an ImageView showing a car icon which is fixed to center of the screen on top of the the Map Fragment. I want to perform some action when the car icon overlaps parking_lot Marker while dragging the Map.

What are the possible ways of doing this?

I'm able to get the LatLong of the car while dragging but i have no idea what to do next.

[image: ss]

Comment: You just need the lat/lon of both points, and then you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8832202/4409409

Comment: I think finding the distance btween two points will help..thanks bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get center of map with this

```
Map.getCameraPosition().target;
```

then you can find distance between users location and center with this method:

```
private static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double theta = lon1 - lon2;
    double dist = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat2)) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta));
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = Math.toDegree(dist);
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    return (dist * 1.609344);
}
```

if distance is lower than a specific value do what you want

Comment: whats doing inside the rad2deg() method?

Comment: convert radians to degree. post edited @ZayidMohammed