# How to calculate distance or displacement from center point of lat long to current gps positions in android

Tags: android, gps, distance, latitude-longitude

How to calculate displacement between center of latitude and longitude point with my current position in android studio?

Condition :

1. if i'm inside the circle area then show "welcome" message.
2. if i'm outside then show "not in area" message

Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Give this a read https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832071/how-can-i-get-the-distance-between-two-point-by-latlng