# measure distance without network

Tags: java, android

I want to know how I can use accelerometer sensor to determine distance that I an walk it at Android device  If it is possible, then how can I implement it?

I use this code but not run. Any answer please??

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    float[] values = event.values;
    int value = -1;
    if (values.length > 0) {
        value = (int) values[0];
    }
    if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {
        steps++;
    }
}

  float distance = (float)(steps*68.475)/(float)100000;
```

Comment: you have acceleration, you have time, therefore you have velocity and distance traveled, it is just math.

Comment: how can obtain the acceleration ?

Comment: it's very common issue, with first hit on google you can get bunch of examples check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292617/how-to-calculate-distance-while-walking-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible: due to the low sensitivity of the built-in accelerometers and the so weak accelerations that are created when a person walks.

Not having network does not mean that GPS does not work ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741403/get-the-distance-between-two-geo-points

Comment: ok i able to obtain the location but i want to save start location and end location and measure distance between them                                                            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
  displaytv.setText("\n"+location.getLatitude()+" \n"+location.getLongitude());     what can i do ??

Comment: You save initial and actual positions in Position variables and then distance =  initialPos.distanceTo(actualPos);