# Show distance and name of nearby markers in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'd like to create textbubbles that show the distance from that marker to the devices location, plus the name given to the marker. These are markers I set in advance:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(51.1691158, 4.4662486)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_marker)));
```

This is an image of the design I had in mind:
[On the bottom of the activity, you should see textbubbles that you can scroll and click on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZTcg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display textbubbles, you can use [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows) from the same Google Maps API.

```
static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(MELBOURNE)
                      .title("Melbourne"));
melbourne.showInfoWindow();
```

and to get the difference between two locations, you can use:

> ```
> Location loc1 = new Location("");
> loc1.setLatitude(lat1);
> loc1.setLongitude(lon1);
>
> Location loc2 = new Location("");
> loc2.setLatitude(lat2);
> loc2.setLongitude(lon2);
>
> float distanceInMeters = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
> ```

The code example is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20600513/9425740).

Reference:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#distanceTo(android.location.Location)
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But please check the image, I don't want infowindows on the markers, but at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Looking at your reference image, you could use a recyclerview since it would be like a horizontal list.
I leave you an example here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94rCjYxvzEE

Comment: Will take a look at that. Thanks